# Fabric check to see file has data

Tags: python, bash, fabric

I want to check whether a file has data inside it, if it has show me what's inside that file, if not exit with "Nothing in the file".  I am using Fabric 1.2 to do this on a remote server.

I am trying this:

```
    def test():
        run("cat myfile.txt | awk '{print $1}' > /dir/newfile.txt")
    if run("test -s /dir/newfile.txt || cat /dir/newfile.txt"):
            else run("echo Nothing in the file")
```

I know this is not the best way of doing this and I know Python uses os.path.getsize(path) for similar purposes.  Can you help at all?

Comment: `file the-file-name` Would print `the-file-name: empty` if the file has no data. Put it together with `grep` and you get `if run("file the-file-name | grep 'the-file-name: empty'"):`

Comment: Yes that does it, should have seen that.  How do I run a else statement, I am getting a syntax error?  Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

There is a simpler command to do that, and it does not require saving anything to a file:

```
file 'the-filename' | grep 'the-filename'
```

So, the code would be:

```
if run("file 'the-filename' | grep 'the-filename'", warn_only=True).succeeded:
    print("The file 'the-filename' is empty.")
else:
    print("The file 'the-filename' is not empty.")
```

The [`succedeed`](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.5/api/core/operations.html?highlight=run#fabric.operations.run) attribute of the return value is `True` if the command succeeded, which happens when `grep` matches the string(i.e. when the file is empty).

Searching in `fabric`'s documentation it does not seem to provide a function like `os.path.getsize`, so you are probably stuck calling commands with `run`.

An other way of doing this could be using `stat 'the-filename' --format=%s | grep '^0$'` and check for `succeeded`.

Comment: Thank you but this answer is only relevant to Fabric 1.5x - I am using 1.2.  warn_only=True isn't available on 1.2.

Comment: However I upgraded to 1.5 and this answer did help so you get my vote.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
@task
def empty():
    some_file = 'some_file'
    run(('if [ -s "%s" ]; then'
         ' cat "%s"; '
         'else'
         ' echo "EMPTY FILE"; '
         'fi') % (some_file, some_file))
```

I tested it against a Redhat Unix system, just uses bash if statement and cat in a single call.